# Angular router-outlet is appending rather than replacing the entire component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a route between two components in Angular 9.

The problem is that when I route it append rather than replacing the entire component.

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zQG0.png)

[image: I want to replace the main page with the text below]

App-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BookComponent } from './components/book/book.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'autorBuscado', component:BookComponent,pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Any Ideas?
If you need more code tell me!

App.component.html

```
<router-outlet><h1>Autores</h1>
<div *ngFor='let autor of autores'>
  <tr>{{ autor["id"] }} {{ autor["firstName"] }} {{ autor["lastName"] }}</tr>
</div>

<form>
  <label for="autor">¿Que autor desea buscar?</label>
  <input name="autor" type="text" [(ngModel)]="autorBuscado">
  <input (click)="detalleAutor()" type="button" id="enviar" value="Buscar">
</form>

<h1>Libros</h1>
<div class="principal">
  <div *ngFor='let libro of libros'>
    <div class="libros">
      <img class="imagenLibro" src='assets/imagenes/{{libro.id}}.png' alt="aaaa">
      <p>Título: {{ libro["name"] }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</router-outlet>
```

Comment: Where do you route when u hit `path: ''` ? And where does the `yeee...` come from?

Comment: I have <base href="/"  in index.html. I added the '/' path in app-routing and it does the same

Comment: The yee comes from BookComponent  where which has book.component,html

Comment: could you please share the code of app.html?

Comment: Of course, I posted it

Comment: why you are writing code inside the `<router-outlet>`? is there any reason? because you can make saperate page/component to load it. and you should have to make different page for it

Comment: Separate `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from the rest of the code.

Comment: And where I put the router outlet?

Comment: in app.component.html

Comment: Just put it at the end of your app.component.html. Simply `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Without any code inside it.

Comment: I have the html code of the books in app.component.html, I thought that because is the main html, maybe it always loads, I need to separate that html code to another component?

Comment: _html code of the books in app.component.html_ - I do not understand this. Why would you have HTML of a one component in a different component? How does it even work when the model is in it's respective component file?

Comment: Move everything inside the <router-outlet> tags into a new component eg: HomeComponent and in the routing file define a path:"" to route to the HomeComponent

Comment: I am going to try the Vinaayakh solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Component HomeComponent with the HTML content as

```
<h1>Autores</h1>
<div *ngFor='let autor of autores'>
  <tr>{{ autor["id"] }} {{ autor["firstName"] }} {{ autor["lastName"] }}</tr>
</div>

<form>
  <label for="autor">¿Que autor desea buscar?</label>
  <input name="autor" type="text" [(ngModel)]="autorBuscado">
  <input (click)="detalleAutor()" type="button" id="enviar" value="Buscar">
</form>

<h1>Libros</h1>
<div class="principal">
  <div *ngFor='let libro of libros'>
    <div class="libros">
      <img class="imagenLibro" src='assets/imagenes/{{libro.id}}.png' alt="aaaa">
      <p>Título: {{ libro["name"] }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change App.component.html to

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Change App-routing.module.ts to

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BookComponent } from './components/book/book.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component:HomeComponent,pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: 'autorBuscado', component:BookComponent,pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```